# How add new document to a collection in a batch?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i use "batch" to add a new document to a collection?, this is my code, this code worked very well, but i have to use batch.

```
await scholarRef
              .doc(sc.id)
              .collection('uniforms')
              .add(uniform)
```

i was trying with batch, dont worked

```
const uniforms= await scholarRef
                  .doc(sc.id)
                  .collection('uniforms')
batch.set(uniforms, uniform)
```

but dont worked, what is the wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [commit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#commit) the batch after changing documents in it.

```
await batch.commit()
```